# D3 time string convert to date

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3.

I have a string stored in a var, below is the var.

```
var expense = {"name":"jim","amount":34,"date":"11/12/2015"};
```

and I want to only show the year of the date.

```
var parser = d3.timeParse("%Y");
expense.date = parser(expense.date);
console.log(expense);
```

but I am just getting null for the date. Anyone know how to fix this? I should get the result:

```
{name: "jim", amount: 34, date: 2015 }
```

Comment: parse the full date and then extract the year from the date or use a regex or string-split ( `expense.date = +expense.date.split('/')[2]` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use d3 date tools, first you have the parse your string to date format

```
const tParser = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y")
```

then use on your string

```
const date = tParser(expense.date)
```

then use d3.timeFormat("%Y")

```
const year = d3.timeFormat("%Y")(date)
```

Or much simpler just split your string as **rioV8** commented

```
expense.date = +expense.date.split('/')[2]
```

Thought it could be useful to know how to use d3 time format works, [more info](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format)